# Byte/char buffer to long and/or double

Tags: c#, performance, arrays, c#-2.0

In my code I need to convert string representation of integers to `long` and `double` values.

String representation is a byte array (`byte[]`). For example, for a number `12345` string representation is `{ 49, 50, 51, 52, 53 }`

Currently, I use following obvious code for conversion to `long` (and almost the same code for conversion to `double`)

```
private long bytesToIntValue()
{
    string s = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("Latin1").GetString(bytes);
    return long.Parse(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

This code works as expected, but *in my case* I want something better. It's because currently I must convert bytes to string first.

In my case, `bytesToIntValue()` gets called about 12 million times and about 25% of all memory allocations are made in this method.

Sure, I want to optimize this part. I want to perform conversions without intermediate string (+ speed, - allocation).

What would you recommend? How can I perform conversions without intermediate strings? Is there a faster method to perform conversions?

**EDIT:**

Byte arrays I am dealing with are always contain ASCII-encoded data. Numbers can be negative. For double values exponential format is allowed. Hexadecimal integers are not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I created C# version of `strol` function. This function comes with CRT and source code of CRT comes with Visual Studio.

The resulting method is almost the same as code provided by @Jon Skeet in his answer but also contains some checks for overflow.

In my case all the changes proved to be very useful in terms of speed and memory.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I perform conversions without intermediate strings?

Well you can easily convert each `byte` to a `char`. For example - untested:

```
private static long ConvertAsciiBytesToInt32(byte[] bytes)
{
    long value = 0;
    foreach (byte b in bytes)
    {
        value *= 10L;
        char c = b; // Implicit conversion; effectively ISO-8859-1
        if (c < '0' || c > '9')
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Bytes contains non-digit: " + c);
        }
        value += (c - '0');
    }
    return value;
}
```

Note that this really *does* assume it's ASCII (or compatible) - if your byte array is actually UTF-16 (for example) then it will definitely do the wrong thing.

Also note that this doesn't perform any sort of length validation or overflow checking... and it doesn't cope with negative numbers. You could add all of these if you want, but we don't know enough about your requirements to know if it's worth adding the complexity.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that there is a easy way to do that,
Please note that it won't work with other encodings, The test shown on my computer that this is only 3 times faster (I don't think it worth it).

The code + test :

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str = "12341234";
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);

        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for(int i = 0; i <   1000000 ;i ++)
        {
            long val = BufferToLong.GetValue(buffer);
        }
        Console.WriteLine (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        sw.Restart();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 1000000 ; i++)
        {
            string valStr = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
            long val = long.Parse(valStr);
        }
        Console.WriteLine (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
}

static class BufferToLong
{

    public static long GetValue(Byte[] buffer) {

        long number = 0;

        foreach (byte currentByte in buffer) {

            char currentChar = (char)currentByte;
            int currentDigit = currentChar - '0';

            number *= 10 ;
            number += currentDigit;

        }

        return number;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but question is not about speed of `long.Parse`. And even if it was, 3x speed increase is a something worth to go for, imho. Think about some process taking 3 hours ;-)

Comment: I'm sure you can scale the job with more servers/cores, Sometimes readability/maintainability worth more than performance. Also, I'm not talking about the speed of `long.Parse`, but the whole process of taking a `Byte[]` and parsing it into `long`.